# Sandwich off days in absents using sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to mark the off days as absent if the leaves are sandwiched

eg: consider off days (example saturday and sunday) as absent days when day before and after off days is absent.

example:

```
23-Nov | "Absent"
24-Nov | "Off Day"
25-Nov | "Off Day"
26-Nov | "Absent"
```

Output required.

```
23-Nov | "Absent"
24-Nov | "Absent"
25-Nov | "Absent"
26-Nov | "Absent"
```

I can't fix it to Saturday or sunday because the off days are not the same for all it could be on Mondays & Tuesdays or through out the week. I have the "shiftId" that is '1' for the "off day"

Comment: downvote. Not clearly specified the question. no example code for the question.

Comment: I assume there's some other status that is neither "Off Day" nor "Absent". What is that? Also, we're leaving "Off Day"s alone if *either* the day preceding or the day following is not "Absent"?

Comment: Use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) but I don't know if that's what you're looking for. Pretty unclear to me, voted to close

Comment: Do you always have 2 off days . does this varies by number

Comment: yes off day could be 1day per week

Comment: Search for "gaps and islands" and you will find ways to solve your task.

Answer (score 0):

You have problems finding an algorithm? It's not so hard. Find out whether a record represents a Saturday or Sunday and for these find the neighboring Friday and Monday accordingly. Here is the pseudo code. Use appropriate date functions and `LAG` and `LEAD` to convert this into proper SQL.

```
select
  day,
  case 
    when weekday(day) = Saturday 
     and status(day-1) = 'Absent'
     and status(day+2) = 'Absent' then 'Absent'
    when weekday(day) = Sunday 
     and status(day-2) = 'Absent'
     and status(day+1) = 'Absent' then 'Absent'
    else status
  end as new_status
from mytable;
```